# TwiBin for twilio, keeps repeating Say after Record

Tags: twilio

```
 <Response>
  <Say voice="man">First Question?</Say>
   <Record timeout="15" transcribe="true" finishOnKey="#" transcribeCallback="https://google.com/first_question_callback" />
   <Say voice="man">Second Question?</Say>
   <Record timeout="15" transcribe="true" finishOnKey="#" transcribeCallback="https://google.com/second_question_callback"/>
  </Response>
```

This code keeps repeating the **first** Say after the **first** Record. It needs to progress to the next Say and the next Records... Can someone help please?

Answer (score 0):

Without an action URL defined, the `Record` verb calls the same TwiML source.

[TwiML™ Voice: Record](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/record#attributes-action)

> Keep in mind that by default Twilio will re-request the current
> document's URL, which can lead to unwanted looping behavior if you're
> not careful. Any TwiML verbs occurring after a  are
> unreachable.

Why don't you use [Twilio Studio](https://www.twilio.com/studio) for this instead?